# How to check an item is saved correctly on database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I was working with my own CMS (I made that with Object Oriented Programming in PHP), when I sent a query to insert in database on that CMS, I always check the query response by assuming that query to a variable and I always checked that to understand the query inserted true or no.

How can I detect Laravel insert query (using `save()` method)  saved an item correctly or not?

For example:

```
$articles=new Article;
$articles->title='test title';
$articles->user_id='2';
$articles->body='This is article body';
$articles->save();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `save` method returns a boolean. `true` means success `false` means it didn't insert (or update!) the record.

Usage:

```
$saved = $articles->save();
if($saved){
    // Hurray!
}
else {
    // Whooops
}
```

From the Laravel source:

```
/**
 * Save the model to the database.
 *
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return bool
 */
public function save(array $options = array())
```

**Note** that in most cases when it can't save the model an exception will be thrown though. This is especially true for all errors that come from the SQL driver itself. For example if a UNIQUE constraint is violated.

Comment: I suggest you delete your own answer. Usually writing an answer to your own question only makes sense if you found the solution yourself (which you didn't ;)). I also added an example similar to the one in your answer.

Comment: OK, Now I will delete it. Thanks anyway. and please wait 2 minute to check your answer tick